# Django decorators . Need help to find a solution for class based views

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-decorators, django-class-based-views

This is the files I'm working on. How do I restrict user to access this page?
I want only admin to access this page. I've tried to use the custom decorators but it shows error for class-based-view. I'm a beginner so anyone can help??

**views.py**

```
class student_register(CreateView):
     model = User
     form_class = StudentSignUpForm
     template_name = 'registration/student_register.html'


   def form_valid(self, form_class):
       user = form_class.save()
     # login(self.request, user)
       return redirect('datapage')
```

**forms.py**

```
class StudentSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
     first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
     last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
     phone_number = forms.CharField(required=True)
     semester = forms.CharField(required=True)
     email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

     class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
          model = User
    

     @transaction.atomic
     def save(self):
         user = super().save(commit=False)
         user.is_student = True
         user.first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
         user.last_name = self.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
         user.email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
         user.username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
         user.password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
         user.password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
         user.save()
         student = Student.objects.create(user=user)
         student.phone_number=self.cleaned_data.get('phone_number')
         student.semester=self.cleaned_data.get('semester')
         student.save()
         return user
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
          path("loginrequest/", views.login_request, name="login"),
          path("logoutrequest", views.logout_request, name="logout"),
          path('student_register/', student_register.as_view(), name='student_register'),
          path('teacher_register/',views.teacher_register.as_view(), name='teacher_register'),
         ]
```

**student_register.html**

```
<div class="container my-3">
<div class="form-group">
  <h3>Register here!</h3>
  <br>
  <form  method="POST" class="post-form"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  {{ form.media}}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**`UserPassesTestMixin`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) as

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin


class StudentRegisterView(UserPassesTestMixin, CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = StudentSignUpForm
    template_name = 'registration/student_register.html'

    def form_valid(self, form_class):
        user = form_class.save()
        # login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('datapage')

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_authenticated and self.request.user.is_superuser
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Mixins instead [`UserPassesTestMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) should be appropriate

```
class IsAdmin(UserPassesTestMixin):
    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_admin

    def handle_no_permission(self):
        return redirect('someview')

class StudentRegister(IsAdmin, CreateView):
    ...
```

Comment: how do I redirect if the user isn't the admin?